# How can i check what user did with SKStoreReviewController modal?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a few questions i could not find an answer to.

1. Can we find out if user tapped cancel/submit?
2. Can we know if user already give review? (To not show him modal again)
3. If user give a review and method to show review modal is called will it appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. Apple handles that
3. No

You can read more [about it here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews).

I include a link to a similar answer I posted that helps provide some insight into how the view is presented if you'd like to see the technical side.

[SKStoreReviewController buttons hidden under keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132247/skstorereviewcontroller-buttons-hidden-under-keyboard/46135745#46135745)

This answer goes into detail about the presentation of the view as well which may be of interest (how often it is shown, when it is not shown, etc)

[Why the SKStoreReviewController does not let me submit a review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057452/why-the-skstorereviewcontroller-does-not-let-me-submit-a-review/45061556#45061556)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. Not tested, but feel free if you have any other ones.

When you decide to run: SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() so the user is prompted with the native "Rate in the app store",
Set and control a timer.
Then in the appdelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground control this timer:
- If the user selected "submit", the app will probably go to background within the next 5 to 10 seconds. So if the app hit this method and the elapsed time is less than (i.e) 10 seconds, than (probably) means that the user went to the Apple Store.
- Meanwhile, if the timer hits 30 seconds, stop the timer and save your guess: The user didn't submit the review.

Also, many apps present a custom popup asking the user if they like the app and if so then they present the native SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()