# About the callback of SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()

Tags: swift, becomefirstresponder, skstorereviewcontroller

If the review popup initiated from a view controller shows up, there isn't a way to switch the window focus back to the view controller when the popup is dismissed due to lack of callback function of `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()`.

I would like to make a call to `becomeFirstResponder()` when the review popup is dismissed. Any idea?

Is there a way to extend the *SKStoreReviewController* and add a callback somehow?

Comment: not sure if this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745157/mechanism-to-detect-display-of-ios-10-3-app-rating-dialog/47457826#47457826

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning this will probably break at some point.

Step 1: add this code to your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let windowClass: AnyClass = UIWindow.self

    let originalSelector: Selector = #selector(setter: UIWindow.windowLevel)
    let swizzledSelector: Selector = #selector(UIWindow.setWindowLevel_startMonitor(_:))

    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(windowClass, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(windowClass, swizzledSelector)

    let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(windowClass, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod!))

    if didAddMethod {
        class_replaceMethod(windowClass, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod!))
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
    }

    return true
}
```

Step 2: add this class

```
class MonitorObject: NSObject {
    weak var owner: UIWindow?

    init(_ owner: UIWindow?) {
        super.init()
        self.owner = owner
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UIWindow.didBecomeVisibleNotification, object: self)
    }

    deinit {
         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UIWindow.didBecomeHiddenNotification, object: self)
    }
}
```

Step 3: Add this UIWindow extension

```
private var monitorObjectKey = "monitorKey"
private var partialDescForStoreReviewWindow = "SKStore"

extension UIWindow {
    // MARK: - Method Swizzling
    @objc func setWindowLevel_startMonitor(_ level: Int) {
        setWindowLevel_startMonitor(level)

        if description.contains(partialDescForStoreReviewWindow) {
             let monObj = MonitorObject(self)
             objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &monitorObjectKey, monObj, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

Step 4: add this to ViewDidLoad of your controller where you want this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(windowDidBecomeHiddenNotification(_:)), name: UIWindow.didBecomeHiddenNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Step 5: add the callback for the notification and check that the associated object is a match

```
@objc func windowDidBecomeHiddenNotification(_ notification: Notification?) {
    if notification?.object is MonitorObject {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

Now when a review dialog is closed the notification is triggered and 'print("hello") will be called.

Comment: Probably because it's considered pretty hacky code, and that it could be cleaned a bit more, or that fact I didn't explain it very well.

Comment: That's fine. I don't think there exists unhacky code coz Apple documentation doesn't say anything about the call back. Thx for the effort!

Comment: Yeah hope they can fix it in the future

Comment: Don't work on iOS 13 but in iOS 12 working, any idea for IOS 13?

Comment: I will look into iOS 13 tonight or tomorrow. First thing that comes to mind is checking if the window description has changed (partialDescForStoreReviewWindow in step 3). Just set a break point and check when you open the review window that the description contains that string. If not you know what to do.

Comment: When dismiss SKStoreReviewController step 3 not called

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes iOS app is losing the responder chain, like in the above example of showing StoreKit prompt. What we can do is to detect such events in `UIApplication.sendAction` and reactivate the first responder chain via `becomeFirstResponder`. UIKit will reestablish the first responder chain and we can resend the same event.

```
class MyApplication: UIApplication {

    func reactivateResponderChainWhenFirstResponderEventWasNotHandled() {
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, from sender: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let wasHandled = super.sendAction(action, to: target, from: sender, for: event)
        if wasHandled == false, target == nil {
            reactivateResponderChainWhenFirstResponderEventWasNotHandled()
            return super.sendAction(action, to: target, from: sender, for: event)
        }
        return wasHandled
    }
}
```

This works for me on iOS 13 and does not require any private API access.